How to create web notification(inbox) by user using Redis stream?
I want to create web notification(inbox) by user using Redis stream.
I'm handling web notification(inbox) with RDB (fields: id, user_id, deep_link, message, created_at) now, but I think it's inefficient in aspect of RDB resource & management.

This image is exactly the type of notification I want.
-> 1)select by user, 2)order by time, 3)types are divided, but notifications look up at once
But in my service, there's 4 types notifications (1.all success 2.all failed 3.partial success 4.not related).
The frame is the same in the 4 notifications, but the details are different such as "{title} - all success", "{item[0]} - partial success".
I asked chat gpt and he answered...

make stream by user
look up by user (stream)
separate by notification type
post-processing separated notifications to create notification phrases

But in my judgement the redis will be too heavy, if there are more users because making stream by user.
Isn't there a more efficient way?
Or I think it's good to use redis hashmap, what do you think?

You can resort to secondary indexing for that. Secondary indexing is already delivered by Redis Stack and soon by Redis 8.
Please download and install Redis Stack. It bundles all the modules, including search, JSON, time series and probabilistic data structures.
The same modules will be integral part of the standard Redis 8 Community Edition. Right now, Redis 8 M02 is out for testing (recommended option but not yet GA).
Provision your data (hash or JSON work, hash is used in the example).
HSET notification:vsdfv2f title "How to merge different contents" active 1 type 1 time 1731573589 user "user1"
HSET notification:rgsfdki title "Show two distinct column count" active 1 type 2 time 1731573631 user "user2"
HSET notification:svfsths title "How to install Django" active 1 type 3 time 1731573728 user "user1" 
HSET notification:h3w52rg title "Sorting data in Redis" active 1 type 3 time 1731573729 user "user1" 
HSET notification:22f5gjh title "How to install Redis" active 1 type 4 time 1731573730 user "user3" 
HSET notification:235u774 title "What is the best method to..." active 1 type 3 time 1731573730 user "user3" 

Create the index on the desired types.
FT.CREATE idx:notification ON HASH PREFIX 1 notification: SCHEMA active NUMERIC user TAG time NUMERIC SORTABLE type NUMERIC

Get all active notifications for the user
FT.SEARCH idx:notification '@active:[1 1] @user:{user1}' SORTBY time ASC RETURN 1 title LIMIT 0 10
1) (integer) 3
2) "notification:vsdfv2f"
3) 1) "title"
   2) "How to merge different contents"
4) "notification:svfsths"
5) 1) "title"
   2) "How to install Django"
6) "notification:h3w52rg"
7) 1) "title"
   2) "Sorting data in Redis"

Set a notification as seen.
HSET notification:vsdfv2f active 0

Search again
FT.SEARCH idx:notification '@active:[1 1] @user:{user1}' SORTBY time ASC RETURN 1 title LIMIT 0 10
1) (integer) 2
2) "notification:svfsths"
3) 1) "title"
   2) "How to install Django"
4) "notification:h3w52rg"
5) 1) "title"
   2) "Sorting data in Redis"

Filter by type
FT.SEARCH idx:notification '@active:[1 1] @user:{user3} @type:[3 3]' SORTBY time ASC RETURN 1 title LIMIT 0 10
1) (integer) 1
2) "notification:235u774"
3) 1) "title"
   2) "What is the best method to..."


Streams are still a good option; you can model streams per user and type if you really need the ability to stream by type
notifications:userid:type
